# Delete request is not getting the Authorization header

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, http-delete

I have my backend in `NodeJs` and `Express`. 90% of my endpoints go through the `validateToken` middlewere and it works well, but I created a `delete` endpoint and for some reason it doesn't get the `Authorization` header even when I am sending it.

This is part of my code:

- **Backend**

```js
// CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
}));
```

```js
// Routes
router.delete('/package/:id', validateToken, isAdmin, deletePackage);
```

```js
exports.validateToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
      return res.status(401).send({error: 'Remember to include the Authorization header'});
    }
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

    if (!decodedToken) {
      return res.status(401).send({error: 'Invalid token'});
    }

    req.user = decodedToken.email;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({error: error});
  }
};
```

- **Frontend**

```js
export const deletePackageApi = id =>
  Request.delete(`/package/${id}`, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
  });
```

This is the response that I am getting only with the `delete` request:

```js
{error: 'Remember to include the Authorization header'}
```

I put it logs in the tha backend and only with the delete endpoint is not getting the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things:

1. I have no idea what `Request` is! Make sure that the `delete` method of `Request` appends headers correctly.
2. Inspect the network (using devTools) to see if the frontend is sending the request with specified headers.

Recommendation: use Fetch/Axios

Answer (score 0):

The error was tha I was sending the header as the body. I had to put an empty object (`{}`) before the header.

```js
export const deletePackageApi = id =>
  Request.delete(`/package/${id}`, {}, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
  });
```